# Number theory problem from the $34th$ all Russian MO

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Given a finite set $P$ of prime numbers, prove that there exists a natural number $x$ such that it can be represented in the form $a^p+b^p$ where $a, b$ are natural numbers for any prime $p$ belonging to $P$, but not representable in the given form for any prime not belonging to $P$.

I started by looking at some small sets of primes. I looked at {$2, 3$} and found that $65$ was the smallest number that could be represented in both forms $65= 2^{2\times3}+1$. This got me thinking that the smallest number representable in both forms for any two coprime numbers $n, m$ would be the number $2^{n\times m}+1$. If I could prove this then the problem would be solved because the desired $x$ would just be $2$ raised to the product of all the primes in the set plus $1$. I tried to make progress with my conjecture but I couldn't come up with anything.

$1)$ Is my conjecture even true? I do not consider the redundant case of $1+1$.

$2)$ If it is, how do I prove it?

Any ideas?

Comment: HINT.-Let $P$ be the product $p_1p_2\cdots p_n$. For all pair $a,b$ of naturals the number $x=a^P+b^P$ is as required ($x=(a^{p_2\cdots p_n})^{p_1}+(b^{p_2\cdots p_n})^{p_1}$ and similarly for the other primes). Choose $a=P$ and $b=P^2$ (you can taken $a=b$ if you want) so you have $$x=P^P+(P^2)^P$$.

This way, if $x=c^q+d^q$ where the prime $q$ is different of the $p_i$ you can get for all $p_i$
$$c^q\equiv -d^q\pmod {p_i}$$ Can you get from this a contradiction?

Comment: I tried, but I cannot find a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

The conjecture is false, because the smallest number representable in both forms for any two coprime numbers $m$ and $n$ is either $0+0=0$ or $1+1=2$ , depending on whether you consider $0$ a natural number or not.

For a less trivial counterexample, consider $n=2$, $m=5$ and
$$3^5+1^5=12^2+10^2=244,$$
which is smaller than $2^{2\times5}+1=1025$.

Comment: I forgot to say that I do not consider the redundant case 1+1, it obviously doesn't satisfy the conditions of the problem.

Comment: @NiksTopics I have added a nontrivial counterexample.

Comment: Well, that apparently destroys all the ideas I had to attack the problem.

Comment: Rather off-topic, I find it a very counterintuitive approach; I don't see how this intermediate result makes the problem any more tractable. I would suggest starting with a natural number of the form $a^p+b^p$ for all $p\in P$, and then scale it up by some factor to ensure that it is not a sum of two $q$-th powers for any other prime $q$. But I recommend you wrestle with it a bit yourself, and perhaps ask a new question if that proves unsuccesful.

Comment: Could you please explain in greater detail how you would do that?

Comment: I won't do that here, as that is a different question entirely; I'll just say that instead of *restricting* your $a$ and $b$ to particular values to 'simplify' the problem (here $a=2$ and $b=1$), you should leverage the freedom you have in choosing *any* $a$ and $b$ to get $x=a^n+b^n$ that works for all $p$ in $P$.